# How to impute data with mlr3 and predict with NA values?

Tags: r, imputation, mlr3

I followed the [documentation](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/impute-missing-variables/) of mlr3 regarding the imputation of data with pipelines. However, the mode that I have trained does not allow predictions if a one column is NA

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

**train step**

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)


data("mtcars", package = "datasets")
data = mtcars[, 1:3]
str(data)
task_mtcars = TaskRegr$new(id="cars", backend = data, target = "mpg")


imp_missind = po("missind")
imp_num     = po("imputehist", param_vals =list(affect_columns = selector_type("numeric")))
scale = po("scale")
learner = lrn('regr.ranger')

graph = po("copy", 2) %>>% 
  gunion(list(imp_num %>>% scale,imp_missind)) %>>%
  po("featureunion") %>>%
  po(learner)
graph$plot()

graphlearner = GraphLearner$new(graph)
```

**predict step**

```
data = task_mtcars$data()[12:12,]
data[1:1, cyl:=NA]
predict(graphlearner, data)
```

The error is

```
Error: Missing data in columns: cyl.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in the [mlr3gallery](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/impute-missing-variables/) seems to work for your case, so you basically
have to switch the order of `imputehist` and `missind`.

Another approach would be to set the missind's `which` hyperparameter to "all" in order to enforce the creation of an indicator for every column.

This is actually a bug, where `missind` returns the full task if trained on data
with no missings (which in turn then overwrites the imputed values).
Thanks a lot for spotting it. I am trying to fix it here [PR](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3pipelines/pull/359)

Comment: Ok I'll try your solution. However I have a question about the possibility of processing only for a few variables. Let's say I have a dataset with 2 categorical variables and 3 numeric variables. I would like to preproces the categorical and numeric variables separately, all in parallel fashion. Is it possible to have an 'po' that allows me to select a few variables for a specific processing?

Comment: yes, have a look at the `affect_columns` hyperparameter in `PipeOpImpute` and use an appropriate `Selector`. This hyperparameter is supported by many `PipeOps`.

The following for example selects only a single column:
`po("imputehist", param_vals = list(affect_columns =selector_name("Sepal.Length")))`

Comment: How can i drop the original factor columns, after endoding them by `po('encode')` ?

Comment: `po(select)` allows for selecting / de-selecting columns.
But `po('encode')` should drop original factor columns by itself.